# IntelliJ always executes tests in gradle project

Tags: gradle, testing, intellij-idea

I get different executions when running `gradle test` from the terminal or from the gradle tool window.

`gradle test` will skip the execution of the tests after a successful run, while with IntelliJ the tests are executed, like `gradle cleanTest test` does.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to do the `UP-TO-DATE` check for tests?

EDIT:
executing `gradlew test` from IntelliJ (gradle toolwindow):

```
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE.
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
```

executing `gradlew test` from terminal:

```
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

executing `gradlew test -i` from terminal:

```
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
```

Caching disabled for task ':compileKotlin' because:
Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':compileKotlin' as it is up-to-date.
:compileKotlin (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.
:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> file or directory '/Users/kevin/vwac/IdeaProjects/intellij-gradle/src/main/java', not found
> Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
> :compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :processResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Skipping task ':processResources' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
> :processResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :classes (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
> :classes (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :compileTestKotlin (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Caching disabled for task ':compileTestKotlin' because:
> Build cache is disabled
> Skipping task ':compileTestKotlin' as it is up-to-date.
> :compileTestKotlin (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.004 secs.
> :compileTestJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> file or directory '/Users/kevin/vwac/IdeaProjects/intellij-gradle/src/test/java', not found
> Skipping task ':compileTestJava' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
> :compileTestJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :processTestResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Skipping task ':processTestResources' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
> :processTestResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :testClasses (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
> :testClasses (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
> :test (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
> file or directory '/Users/kevin/vwac/IdeaProjects/intellij-gradle/build/classes/java/test', not found
> Caching disabled for task ':test' because:
> Build cache is disabled
> Skipping task ':test' as it is up-to-date.
> :test (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.

I could not figure out add the `-i` flag for gradle tasks running from IntelliJ, so I don't have any insights there

Comment: **I get different executions -** What do you mean?

Comment: I updated the question with the results from executing `gradlew test` from IntelliJ and terminal

Comment: IDE always executes `test` task. See a related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240111/Gradle-Runner-disables-incremental-build-for-Test-tasks-always-r